# Why the confint() result changed in every times?

Tags: r

When I run a GEE, i use glht() for Post hoc test, after that, i use confint() to get the value of 95%CI. But what strange is that the result changed every times, when i run the code again and again. Why?

```
library(multcomp)
library(geepack)
data(dietox)
#dietox$Weight = as.integer(dietox$Weight)
dietox$Cu <- as.factor(dietox$Cu)
mf <- formula(Weight ~ Cu + Time + I(Time^2) + I(Time^3))
gee1 <- geeglm(mf, data=dietox, id=Pig, corstr="ar1")
CI <- glht(gee1,mcp("Cu" = "Tukey"))
confint(CI)


result:
                   Estimate lwr     upr    
Cu035 - Cu000 == 0 -0.4467  -3.7996  2.9061
Cu175 - Cu000 == 0  1.1821  -2.9923  5.3565
Cu175 - Cu035 == 0  1.6288  -2.6616  5.9193

run the code again:
                   Estimate lwr     upr    
Cu035 - Cu000 == 0 -0.4467  -3.8002  2.9067
Cu175 - Cu000 == 0  1.1821  -2.9931  5.3573
Cu175 - Cu035 == 0  1.6288  -2.6624  5.9201

again:
                   Estimate lwr     upr    
Cu035 - Cu000 == 0 -0.4467  -3.7985  2.9050
Cu175 - Cu000 == 0  1.1821  -2.9910  5.3552
Cu175 - Cu035 == 0  1.6288  -2.6603  5.9179
.......
```

Comment: From the help of `confint.glht`: "_Note that the default procedure is stochastic. Reproducible p-values and confidence intervals require appropriate settings of seeds._" Write `set.seed(1234)` before `confint(CI)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it seems that when using confint () to solve the confidence interval for linear regression, the result does not change in real-time. Why?  
fit <- lm(100/mpg ~ disp + hp + wt + am, data = mtcars)
confint(fit)

Comment: `confint.lm` (i.e. the calculation of CIs for linear models) is not a stochastic procedure. Thus, the commands `fit <- lm(100/mpg ~ disp + hp + wt + am, data = mtcars) confint(fit)` give the same result for each run. The method used by `confint.glht` is different and is stochastic (maybe based on bootstrap).